# Team City how to have non blocking build step when running exe

Tags: teamcity

We've recently found that an acceptance test project fails occasionally on our build server- due to our web drivers Type is not resolved error. I'm trying an experiment to see if its a question of timing of build steps. To this end I've tried to create a separate build step which launches the webdriver executable separately and then proceed onto the unit tests - the issue I have is when I launch the process it blocks the next step after it has successfully started.

eg. Type is not resolved for member 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException,WebDriver, Version=2.41.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'..

Is there a way I can progress to the next build step after I call an exe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple build agents?  Have you considered splitting this into separate build configurations and having triggers on previous build configurations?

You could have configurations:

- Compile,
- Webdriver, triggered on successful compile completion
- Unit Tests, triggered on successful compile completion.

It's not nice, but it should give you the non-blocking behavior you're after.  I can't see any other way of making it happen, build configurations are supposed to run as a linear sequence.